# Magick Wand: Convert SVG to PNG (with embedded images)

Tags: python, image, svg, png, wand

I have an SVG document with an embedded JPEG image (placed in the same directory) which I'd like to convert to PNG in Python.

```
<image x="20" y="20" width="300" height="80" xlink:href="./pattern.jpg" />
```

Currently, I'm using Wand which does create a PNG image that contains all SVG objects but not the embedded image.

```
with Image(filename='data/output.svg') as image:
    image.save(filename='data/output.png')
```

Any ideas how to solve this? Thank you very much!

Comment: If it's a png image, why does the href end .jpg?

Comment: Sorry, the embedded image is of course a JPG. Doesn't matter though, any embedded image will not be visible in the output PNG.

Comment: i experience similar issue with 'bartik' while converting svg to png. to solved this by giving absolute path to image. so in your case try giving full image path like xlink:href="http://www.xyz.com/pattern.jpg" and then check

Comment: Thanks, but I've already tried that. Still no change.

Comment: I've tried with `inkscape` and `rsvg-convert` now. Inkscape works, whereas rsvg does not. I really don't understand...

Answer (score 0):

Wand can process the image without the "./" just specify the file if it's in the same location

If the image is not in the same location, then you have to use the inkscape.